# How to handle interrupts or completed with cURL

Tags: php

My php script downloads files from a remote server using cURL. I wanted to monitor the bandwidth that was being used when downloading the file so what I did was put an SQL update query within the write_callback function. This works like a charm but im worried that the database will have troubles if a script like this is updating data every 10 miliseconds or so.  Does cURL have a "completed" call back function? so that the script will collect the amount of bytes that were downloaded then update ONLY once when its been completed? And also does the cURL have some type of interruption callback or incomplete? so when users kill the download it somehow recognizes that and subtracts the bytes that were downloaded in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

// ... set whatever options you need

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function ($ch, $data) {
  global $bytes;
  $bytes += strlen($data);
  // Write data here
});

$bytes = 0;
$starttime = microtime(TRUE);

curl_exec();

$endtime = microtime(TRUE);
$totaltime = $endtime - $starttime;

// You would do your DB update here
echo "Downloaded $bytes bytes in $totaltime seconds (".($bytes / $totaltime)." bytes/second)";
```

Handling interupts would be more difficult, but maybe you could use [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)? I don't know if this actually gets called when the script receives SIGINT, though. You may also be able to use [`pcntl_signal()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) if it is available.

Comment: Thank you for your support, the register_shutdown_function() fixed my whole problem! :)

Comment: @Zakukashi I am using `register_shutdown_function` for curl. So are you passing the curl response also while calling the shutdown_function?

Comment: @AnishNair You can't pass arguments to the shutdown function, but you can import data. The usually easy but very ugly way is via `global`, however you can use a method of an object instance as the shutdown handler, so you can store any data you want to be available to your handler in an object property. [Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3igbdc).

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you for your answer. I am doing it using global variables. And btw, we can pass arguments to the `register_shutdown_function`

Comment: @AnishNair do you use `register_shutdown_function` to catch curl network interruption or did you mean something different?